# ROS graph output into LaTeX file?

Tags: ros, rosgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

do you have an idea on how I can decently insert a ROS graph output of my stack into a LaTeX file? I have tried exporting it as a DOT file and converting that to TIKZ. It works. But it's faaaaar too big. And it's not using TIKZ nodes but primitives like ellipses instead. That way it's pretty much unmaintainable.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151626/ros-graph-output-into-latex-file?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I convert the DOT output to PDF and then include the PDF file as a regular figure in Latex.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0